# Font-size change too sharply for 1px

Tags: css

I have some css

```
.welcomeBody h1{
    font-family: "Gill Sans";
    font-size: 95px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: rgb(166,172,176);
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
.welcomeBody h2{
    color: rgb(229,153,88);
    font-family: "Gill Sans";
    font-size:32px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
```

For the h2, when I set 32px to 31px for welcomeBody h2, in my webpage, the font becomes so small sharply. It seems that the font-size have come to 10px...Why? I just decrease 1px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet. The two h2's are almost the same size. What's the issue?

```css
.welcomeBody h1{
    font-family: "Gill Sans";
    font-size: 95px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: rgb(166,172,176);
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

h2{
    color: rgb(229,153,88);
    font-family: "Gill Sans";
    font-size:32px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.welcomeBody h2{
    color: rgb(229,153,88);
    font-family: "Gill Sans";
    font-size:31px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class=welcomeBody>This is the h1</h1>
<h2 class=welcomeBody>This is the 31px h2</h2>
<h2 >This is the 32px h2</h2>
```

Comment: Yes 0.0 By doing this, it fix my problem, however,do you know why?

Comment: By doing what? There was no problem in the first place. I'm just showing you what you get with 31 and 32 px.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this about responsive sizing for fonts. 
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/webdesign/viewport-units/